# A tricky haskell problem

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I  had this task for my Haskell class, but I find it quite difficult. If you could help a bit.
You are given a maze

```
maze = ["x xxx",
        "x   x",
        "x x x",
        "x x  ",
        "xxxxx"]
```

and you can walk through spaces only . You start from (0,1) and the function have to return a string with directions to escape the maze which are :

```
f - forward
r- turn right
l - turn left
```

And if you have a choice you always prefer right to forward, and forward to left.
 For the current example the answer is `ffllffrffrfflf`

Thanks in advance

```
data Direction = N | W | S | E deriving (Show,Eq)

maze = ["x xxx",
        "x   x",
        "x x x",
        "x x  ",
        "xxxxx"]

d = 's'
pos = (0,1)

fpath d pos | fst pos == (length maze - 1) = ""
            | snd  (pos) ==0 || (snd ( pos ) == ((length (maze!!0))-1)) = ""
            | rightPossible d pos = "r" ++ ( fpath (rightRotate d) pos )
            | forwardPossible d  pos = "f" ++ ( fpath d (nstep d pos) )
            | True = "l" ++ fpath (leftRotate d) pos
            where nstep :: Direction -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) {-next step-}
                  nstep N (x,y) = (x-1,y)
                  nstep W  (x,y) = (x,y-1) 
                  nstep S (x,y) = (x+1,y) 
                  nstep E  (x,y) = (x,y+1)

                  rightPossible :: Direction -> (Int, Int) -> Bool 
                  rightPossible N (x,y)= (maze !! x)!! (y+1) == ' '
                  rightPossible W (x,y)= (maze !! (x-1))!! y   == ' '              
                  rightPossible S (x,y)= (maze !! x)!! (y-1) == ' '                   
                  rightPossible E (x,y)= (maze !! (x+1))!! y   == ' '

                  rightRotate :: Direction -> Direction 
                  rightRotate N = E
                  rightRotate W = N
                  rightRotate S = W
                  rightRotate E = S

                  forwardPossible :: Direction -> (Int, Int) -> Bool 
                  forwardPossible N (x,y)= ((maze !! (x-1))!! y) == ' ' 
                  forwardPossible W (x,y)= ((maze !! x)!! (y-1)) == ' '
                  forwardPossible S (x,y)= ((maze !! (x+1))!! y) == ' '
                  forwardPossible E (x,y)= ((maze !! x)!! (y+1)) == ' '

                  leftRotate :: Direction -> Direction
                  leftRotate N = W
                  leftRotate W = S
                  leftRotate S = E
                  leftRotate E = N
```

Comment: Now, where is the question? What did you do already? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Use the ["Wall follower"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) ;)

Comment: I am beginer in Haskell, i had previous experience with functional languagees. I know that I need to reqursively solve this, but I can not implemet it in Haskel.

Comment: @ivanv Can you still tell us, where you got stuck? If you can solve this task, try to explain as much as possible.

Comment: I've got two problems 1) I keep getting this error "Instances of (Num [Char], Num Char) required for definition of fpath" and 2) I don't think this solution if fixed to work is very functional-style

Comment: The answer `ffllffrffrfflf` does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Also I do not think that the constraint “if you have a choice you always prefer right to forward, and forward to left” is well-defined.  What prevents you from turning right 100 times before starting?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: I would assume that means "take the rightmost branch from an intersection", equivalent to "turn right and move forward" as a single action. Note that this can still go in circles given a loop in the pathways.

Comment: Please format code properly (without tabs) before posting.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing I see is, that you have a precedence issue. The expression `(maze !! x)!! y-1` is parsed as `((maze !! x)!! y)-1` whereas you want it parsed as `(maze !! x)!! (y-1)`. Add braces to solve this issue.

After adding this, your code compiles, although your algorithm seems to be broken. Maybe somebody else can help you.

Some coding advises:

- Add type signatures at appropriate places to ease debugging. (If the type fails, the compiler will more likely show the error in the right place)
- Use pattern matching instead of extra case statements. Instead of

  ```
  nstep d (x,y)   {-next step-}
                  | d == 'n' = (x-1,y)
                  | d == 'w' = (x,y-1)
                  | d == 's' = (x+1,y)
                  | d == 'e' = (x,y+1)
  ```

  write

  ```
  nstep 'n' (x,y) = (x-1,y)
  nstep 'w' (x,y) = (x,y-1)
  nstep 's' (x,y) = (x+1,y)
  nstep 'e' (x,y) = (x,y+1)
  ```
- Write your own `data` types instead of relying on characters. For instance, you could create an own datatype for directions:

  ```
  data Direction = N | W | S | E deriving (Show,Eq)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with FUZxxl. If you make a new data type, you can do stuff like

Data types

> ```
> data Direction = North | West | South | East deriving (Show,Eq) 
> type Point = (Int, Int)
> ```

Using the data types in a readable and efficient way

> ```
> nstep :: Direction -> Point -> Point
> nstep North (x,y) = (x-1,y)
> nstep West  (x,y) = (x,y-1) 
> nstep South (x,y) = (x+1,y) 
> nstep East  (x,y) = (x,y+1)
> ```

Again here. Also, using well-named functions instead of just `r`, which doesn't mean much.

> ```
> rightPossible :: Direction -> Point -> Bool
> rightPossible North = (maze !! x)!! (y-1) == ' '
> rightPossible West  = (maze !! x+1)!! y   == ' '              
> rightPossible South = (maze !! x)!! (y+1) == ' '                   
> rightPossible East  = (maze !! x-1)!! y   == ' '
> ```
>
> Hope this helps you understand the language a little.

edit: changed `data Point` to `type Point`

Comment: Thanks!!!
That helped me a lot but got an infinite recursion although I have triple checked the code.

Comment: Did you check that you don't add positions you already have visited?

Comment: Inevitably I should go through the same position more than once in case I reach a dead end. Going and returning back from a dead end should be also included in the journey. And this is normal. If only I had a decent debugger :(

Comment: Also, just thought of a really neat way to do turnRight http://codepad.org/sDYMvSRp. succ is a standard Prelude function. Using pred instead would give you turnLeft.

Comment: When you reach a junction (more than one possible direction), call the function for both directions and see which one gets you out.  Don't think about back-tracking manually.  A simply-connected maze (like this one) is a tree where every junction is a node.  So you just need to walk the tree until you find the node with the exit.

Comment: I don't think that's helpful is the solution is *supposed* to be a backtracking path. I think it might be true that you should never be in the same position facing the same direction twice, though.